# XSLT transformation in out sequence for an ESB 4.7.0 service wont execute

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2-esb

I am trying to call an XSLT transformation in the out sequence for an ESB service but I get an error....

I have a WSO2 Data Services Server which returns XML and I have successfully proxied that in the ESB. But when I add the Out sequence....

```
 <outSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
     <xslt key="out_transform2"/>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
```

The XSLT is in a local service and has been tested separately in a .xsl file using PHP. I get...

> 15:14:43,508 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-2] INFO To:
>   http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: ,
>   SOAPAction: , MessageID:
>   urn:uuid:4e28dd11-6720-4f40-9714-6fa7ebd5630f, Direction: response,
>   MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0,
>   ERROR_MESSAGE = Unable to perform XSLT transformation using : Value
>   {name ='null', keyValue ='out_transform2'} against source XPath :
>   s11:Body/child::*[position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[position()=1]
>   reason : Error creating XSLT transformer using : Value {name ='null',
>   keyValue ='out_transform2'}, Envelope:

```
<?xml version='1.0'
encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><users
xmlns="http://test.org"><users><user_id>1745</user_id><fname>john</fname>
<lname>smith</lname></users><users><user_id>7461</user_id><fname>Happy</fname>
...
<lname>claus</lname></users></users></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

...in the Mediation Message tracer.
My XSLT is an Inlined XML entry

```
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="out_transform2">
      <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<!-- snipped content out here !-->    
      </xsl:stylesheet>
</localEntry>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can see this error when WSO2 can't find or can't load your XSLT.

In your case, I can see the same string "out_transform2" used to name your local entry and to reference it in XSLT mediator configuration : it seems to be correct.

I guess that WSO2 can find, but can't load your XSL because there is a problem inside the local entry : you should edit the file out_transform2.xml on the file system with an XML editor and verify it.

Comment: I have tested my XSL as a separate file and it works fine. The error I get from 'try it' is.. <TryitProxyError h:status="SOAP envelope error" xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out</TryitProxyError>